# upload image to database using PHP class PDO, jquery,

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

am having a bug in my script; am trying to upload an image to mysql and am using PHP PDO, classes and jquery. I am sure the script is seeing the image name. i was firstly getting an error message of undefined variable 'img' not declared, but i fixed that using the isset(function), but still no image is inserted, and i get an empty alert message. Sorry to say, am new here. here is my code.

```
form.php // html for inputs
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file"  name ="myimage" id="image">
<input type="submit" id="imageSend" >
</form>

image.js // the image script

$("#imageSend").click(function(){

var postImg = $("#image").attr("name");// image name

var dataString = 'img='+postImg;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"postimage.php",
    data:dataString,
    success: function(html){
    alert(html);
   },
 });
});


postimage.php // script to post image
//class script included here

if(isset($_FILES['img'])){
$image = $_FILES['img'];

$class = new scriptimage();

$class->sendimage($image);
}


class script.php // class script

class scriptimage {

 public $dns = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inspirationaldb";
        public $root ="root";
        public $dbpass ="";
        public $conn;

        //connection string
 public function Connection(){
$this->conn = new PDO($this->dns, $this->root, $this->dbpass);
$this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }

 public function sendimg($uploadname){
 $this->Connection();
 $image_name = $uploadname['name'];
 $image_size = $uploadname['size'];
 $image_type = $uploadname['type'];
 $image_tmp     = $uploadname['tmp_name'];

            if($image_size > 1048576){// 1 MB
                echo "Large Image";
                return false;
            }  

 $path ="post-images/";
 $image_exe = $this->GetImgExtntion($image_type);
 $imageFolderPath = $path.$image_name.$image_exe;
 $imageDBpath = $imageFolderPath;

 if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $imageFolderPath)){

 $save=$this->conn->prepare("insert into images(image)values(:upload)");

$done=$save->execute(array(":upload" =>$imageDBpath));

if($done){
 echo "image saved";
}
else{
   echo "image not saved";
     }
   }
}
```

i do all this and nothing happens, no feedback or image in the database.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. First error I see `$save=$this->conn->prepare("insert into images("image")values(:upload)");`...

Comment: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ try this

Comment: sorry, i skipped that part... i have an else statement after the if...

Comment: Also, you are posting to the form method, AND Ajax method

Comment: i don't really want the page to reload.... should i be posting to just the form method?